# Spark write issue

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying save Data in orc format in s3 using spark in java.i am able to connect s3 but write not writing any data into s3 path but no errors. I checked my dataframe has more than 10k records. I observed that _temporary is getting created and deleted in s3 path but I see no data. Please help with issue

Comment: It would be good if you can add your code and screenshot of spark ui.. it will help others to help you..